# What's the recommended way to use/install webapps on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, nginx, web-application

I'm trying to figure out the best way to robustly setup webapps on my Arch Linux + nginx server. The way I used to do it before was to download and unpack e.g. latest version of dokuwiki/wordpress into `/srv/http/`, and then setup it manually via editing config files in this location, after changing ownership of the directory to the `nginx` user. Everytime a new version of a webapp (one without a builtin upgrade mechanism) came out, I would repeat the procedure, while moving existing config/data files from the old to new location.

However, there surely has to be a better way of maintaining (installing, upgrading, backing up) these webapps, especially considering `pacman` has many of these in its repositories.

I have a few concerns with this approach, though, and a few questions regarding best practices when maintaining webapps on a server:

- the files installed from packages in Arch tend to go into `/usr/share/webapps/`. What about data / config files? Do I put them in there too? Or do I symlink them in somehow? Do I somehow automatically copy apps from there to `/srv/http` after every update?
- assuming I symlink these directories or configure nginx to read directly from these, what about permissions? Will I need to manually run `chown -R root:nginx /usr/share/webapps/new_webapp` after every update/installation? Or are their ownerships automatically set to some `www` group?
- last but not least, what about config files of these webapps when their packages are upgraded? Won't they get overwritten (in worst case) by `pacman` or will tons of `.pacnew` files be created (in the best case)?

How do webadmins normally solve this problem? What resources are there describing best practices in this matter? I am already using puppet to manage configuration of various packages, but "proper" and easy on maintenance way of installing webapps still escapes me.

Comment: Consider asking this question on [sf].

Comment: Wouldn't they just close that there, too? I think they have a no opinion-based questions over there as well. Besides, I had the impression that the difference between these two sites are that SF accepts only strictly professional/corporate environment admin questions, while SU is more lenient on that?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I found [an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53625). I may try asking it on SF, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For manually installed apps, consider downloading the Git or Hg repository if there is one.** You'll be able to update to the latest (stable or development) version with one command *and* keep track of your own code changes if you end up making any. (And if someone finds a way to litter your files with malware, that also takes moments to clean up.)

This sped up updating our two Moodle installations from 30–60 minutes (downloading; extracting; making a backup; re-adding modules; re-applying local patches) to just 1–3 minutes (git pull).

Alternatively, you could create your own packages for pacman, which will then take care of removing the old files and extracting new ones to the right place.

---

Packages also always include the ownership information, so that's usually not a problem.

Manual updates mean that ownership usually needs to be reset, though this can be automated to some point: with in-place updates (e.g. Git/Hg or rsync or such), you can set the "setgid" mode on the webapp's data directories using `chmod g+s`, and the *group* (the `:nginx` part) will be automatically applied to all new files inside.

However, when you extract a new tarball, you'll always need to fix the files manually.

---

For the main location, `/usr/share/webapps` is fine. You don't always need symlinks, often it is more convenient to configure the location directly in httpd.conf; for example:

```
Alias /myapp /usr/share/webapps/MyApp/public
```

For configuration, it depends on your download method. The system-packaged webapps usually have their config files symlinked to /etc, mostly to conform better with the Linux filesystem hierarchy.

When installing from a tarball, a symlink is also more convenient whenever you need to upgrade.

With Git/Hg-based updates, your edits are kept anyway, so it's mostly a matter of preference.

Comment: That cleared some stuff up, especially with the group ownership being taken care of by the packages. The git/hg suggestion is an especially interesting one, what you're saying about changes introduced there being easily tracked; I didn't think of that before. However, I already track the changes in my configuration files via versioning my puppet directory, so I think I'll stick to that + linking the `/usr/share/webapps` directory in the config files. Thanks!